# What does it mean when Kenshin says 'oro'?

Tags: japanese-language, rurouni-kenshin

Throughout the series Kenshin has added 'oro' somewhat comedically to his sentences. Is there any actual meaning to this or is this just a speech style/pattern that he has?

In episode 62 he says it several times in a row and Kaoru points this out.
[image: You said oro?]

Comment: related answer: http://anime.stackexchange.com/a/22463/63

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Oro):

> **A Japanese expression of confusion. Often used by otaku to indicate confusion/disorientation.** People who read/watch "Rurouni Kenshin" may pick up the habit of saying "Oro!" because Himura Kenshin says it often in the manga/anime.

From [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Himura_Kenshin) on Himura Kenshin:

> **Nobuhiro Watsuki added Kenshin's trademark "oro" as a placeholder to be an expression of the English speech disfluency "huh"**. Watsuki notes that he was surprised at how much it caught on, and how much he ended up having Kenshin use the sound during the series

You can watch a few of his Oro moments [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uGrOxc8cOuA)  (and see that he usually uses it when he's confused/disoriented).

Answer (score 0):

Oro, is nothing more than a confused portmanteau for uttering a word that has no real meaning. Similar to Dale Gribbles use of the word "G'h" when surprised or excited.