# What is this guy with a cross scar on his left cheek reference of?

Tags: danna-wakaranai-ken

In the first episode of *Danna ga Nani wo Itteru ka Wakaranai Ken*, there is a scene of the husband proclaiming his hate towards working. His face changed to that of some character with a scar on his left cheek. His speech pattern also changed to that of a samurai:

> Hataraki takunai degozaru! Zettai ni hataraki takunai degozaru!

What is the reference in this scene?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a internet meme in Japan, that a collage picture from [Rurouni Kenshin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rurouni_Kenshin) manga and the text "I hate to work, I certainly hate to work."

[image: Meme]

### Reference

- [Nicopedia's entry on 「働きたくないでござる」](http://dic.nicovideo.jp/a/%E5%83%8D%E3%81%8D%E3%81%9F%E3%81%8F%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%E3%81%A7%E3%81%94%E3%81%96%E3%82%8B) (Japanese)

Comment: For further reading (in Japanese), see e.g. [Nicopedia's entry on 「働きたくないでござる」](http://dic.nicovideo.jp/a/%E5%83%8D%E3%81%8D%E3%81%9F%E3%81%8F%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%E3%81%A7%E3%81%94%E3%81%96%E3%82%8B).

Answer (score 8):

It is a reference to Himura Kenshin, from [Rurouni Kenshin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rurouni_Kenshin).

[image: Himura Kenshin]

This is noted not only by the scar, but also by the way [the sentences are ended](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/121/49).

Comment: Does this character say anything similar to what he was saying "I don't want to work."

Comment: I can't recall any particular moment when he said something like that, no.

Answer (score -1):

Himura Kenshin is also known as the "Hitokiri Battousai", Battousai the Manslayer, Rurouni Kenshin.